# firebase auth android_assets 404 file missing

Tags: cordova, firebase, angularfire, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic + Angular + Firebase + Cordova to build a mobile app.

I have setup Firebase to use the built in authentication and it all works fine except I keep getting this error.

```
GET file:///android_asset/www/%7B%7Blogin.img%7D%7D  ionic.bundle.js:11457
```

I have not used a file with this name, it looks like it is getting created by during the Android build process. I do not know what it is or where it is found. Does any one have any ideas what it could be and how to fix it?

Here is some console.log output from chrome:/inspect devtool

```
User attempting login.. servicesAuth.js:36
anonymous:-JinFLoKny8q9T6c0gvf servicesAuth.js:53
GET file:///android_asset/www/%7B%7Blogin.img%7D%7D  ionic.bundle.js:11457  404 file not found

Object {uid: "anonymous:-JinFLoKny8q9T6c0gvf", provider: "anonymous", anonymous: Object, token: "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ2IjowLCJkI…U4M30.eRrmKcYnViDw_XvnJsVRbaxWJcCT_otR3h1a5Ewekg4", auth: Object…}
```

Thanks,
Darren

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the cause after lots of debugging and research.

```
%7B%7Blogin.img%7D%7D is basically {{login.img}}
```

The braces were getting converted somehow when using an img src tag.
I replaced img src with  img ng-src and all the errors went away!

Hopefully this will help someone else.